# Unable to setState inside of a function

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, state

I am having trouble with being able to set the state of a variable inside a function after that function is called and has a value passed to it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I've tried a lot of different things and looked at lots of different examples but can't seem to get it to work.

Heres the function I'm calling:

```
_onSectionListPress = function(id) {
            const tempID = id;
            this.setState({ jobId: tempID });
            alert(this.state.jobId);
        };
```

And here is where I'm calling the function from and passing a value into it:

```
<FlatList
          style={styles.jobs}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                 onPress={this._onSectionListPress.bind(this, item.id)}
            >
               <ListItem 
                   title={`${item.text}`}
               />
             </TouchableOpacity>
           )}
            keyExtractor={extractKey}                        
/>
```

I have also tried not using

```
onPress={ this._onSectionListPress(item.id) }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So, what happens? any errors? warnings? infinite loop? what are the debug results of `this.state.jobId`

Comment: i don't think this is the reason of bug but i reccomend you to use onPress method like that `onPress={()=> this._onSectionListPress(item.id) }`

Comment: There is no error/bug/warnings, but the state does not get set. However it still asses in the ID variable and I can do ```alert(id)``` and get the value that I want to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may be running into is that `setState` is actually asynchronous.

[From the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

`setState` can have a second parameter which is a callback after the change has been applied. Try using the code below and see if you have more luck:

```
_onSectionListPress = function(id) {
  this.setState({ jobId: id}, () => alert(this.state.jobId));
};
```

Comment: Holy shit thank you so much. I spent so long trying to work this out and this worked. You're a life saver.

Comment: Not a problem @Felis :)